# Gnome 3 global keybinds gone after update

Tags: gnome, gnome3, key-binding, arch-linux

Yesterday I did a full system update (the old one dates back less than a month) and now all my global keybindings don't work anymore. They are created via "gconf-editor" and are located in /apps/metacity/keybindings_commands and global_keybindings. I noticed that there are now only my user generated ones whereas before global_keybindings and keybinding_commands was full of placeholders like run_command_1, run_command_2,....

A search for run_command (include key names) only finds my user defined ones as well so it doesn't seem like they have moved.

A google search for "gnome 3 keybindings moved" didn't find anything with search restriction to the last month.

I updated with "sudo pacman -Su" (I am using Arch Linux).

Comment: Gnome3 uses, as far as I know, *dconf*...maybe they migrated the keybindings over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent from Gnome 3 and other desktop or windmow managers, you can you xbindkeys as a daemon for keyboard and mouse shortcuts.

> xbindkeys is a program that allows you to launch shell commands with your keyboard or your mouse under X Window. (http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html)

Comment: Additional question: How can I autostart xbindkeys? There doesn't seem to be a daemon and when I put `nohup xbindkeys &` in my ~/.xinitrc, nothing happens.